# Read Epub3 in ios app

Tags: iphone, ios, xhtml, epub3

I am learning on epub reader app. I have tried and parsed the epub 2. I found that it has a `opf` file which refer to `toc.ncx` file which is actually a xml file and I can parse it to get the content and html files. Than I can display it in `UIWebView`.

I tried with same approach to parse the epub 3 file. I got the `.opf` file and parse it but the problem is there is no `.ncx` file. It has `toc.xhtml` file. It is the index file what I needed but in `xhtml` format. I am not sure if all files have same format or not. If all epub3 has same format than I can created a custom HTML parser according to my requirement.

Is there any efficient epub3 reader sample available for ios? I found one [here](https://github.com/readium/readium-sdk) but it contains errors and there is nothing mentioned for configuring it.

Any help please.

Comment: How were you able to come up with toc.xhtml parser which I think is now common for all EPUB 3. ? As you have worked on EPUB can you also clear one more thing for me, how were you able to calculate page numbers  as it is dependent on view ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know of two iOS EPUB3 readers these are iBooks and Gitden reader.

EPUB3 must contain a navigation file based on HTML5
See: http://www.heliconbooks.com/article/epub3navdoc

You can simply display this file as standard HTML file, however notice that this file must contain semantic tags like 
There may be more then one  section in each TOC file.
This file is pointed to by the OPF file, in the manifest section there should be one and only one item with property="nav"